# Ensure Ordering of Few Messages in given Set of messages

Tags: java, android, mobile, apache-kafka

**Suppose i have 51 msgs produced by MobileApp .**

I want that **51th msg** should hit the Application server after all 50 are processed . but i don't need ordering for other 50 msgs.
They can hit in any order(Should be parallel) .

Currently i am using Kafka as message broker .

**Major Restriction** :- **I cannot put any callback mechanism on mobile App to give 51th message only after i received 50th message** .

Any ideas around this or links/pointers ??

Answer (score 0):

If you can send (synchronously with commits) the 51 messages in order and use the partitioner to send all messages in a sequence to the same partition (perhaps by making the userid the message's key), you will be assured of reading those messages in order.

Comment: I want first 50 messages should have high concurrency rate . 51th msg should always be the last one .I think by your approach all 51 will have sequential order